# Default Perl vs. perlbrew version on macOS Sierra 10.12.4

Tags: perl, macos-sierra, perlbrew

I'm tryng to instruct my system to permanently use perlbrew version of perl in my shells as per perlbrew documentation with:

```
perlbrew switch perl-5.26.0
```

which should use ~/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.26.0/bin/perl in every new open shell.
But when I close and reopen iTerm2 and ask

```
perl -v
```

the answer is

*This is perl 5, version 24, subversion 1 (v5.24.1) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level*

which is system perl, in the path 
/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.24.1/bin/perl

No chances to swith to different perl release other than current shell.

I have in my .bash_profile:
source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc

as per perlbrew instructions

What am I missing to have permanently perl switched to desired version?

Thank you

Comment: Does it execute the .bash_profile at all?

Comment: I guess it DOES, since there are no reported error messages at shell login

Comment: Please test this for me: Enter `bash -l` and try again. (That's a lowercase "L")

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after googling and struggling, I got to a solution at last.
I started all it over again from Perlbrew documentation, and I did:

1. `perlbrew init`
2. Next, from what it replied to me,
   I added

`source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc`

to my .bash_profile file.

Now, at last, every new shell opens with desired perlbrew switched perl version.

Thank you all, hope this can be useful.